# phonegap Jquery check data connection before request

Tags: jquery

I have jquery code for sending current coordinates to server every 30 seconds.
It works well in areas with good data coverage signals. However, it crashes when the signal is unstable(data coverage is available and disappears repeatedly). After few times the app simply crashes without any warning on the try...catch section.

I need to check if data coverage is available, then constantly send coordinates to server, otherwise just keep on checking again until data coverage is available.

Here is my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js">
     </script>

     <script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="main.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
   <script>


    var netCoverage = false;
    var lat='';
    var lon='';


    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", onDeviceReady, false);






    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 0; //'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 1; //'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 2; //'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 3; //'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 4; //'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 5; //'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 6; //'No network connection';

        //alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
        if(states[networkState]!=0 && states[networkState]!=6)
                netCoverage = true;
        else
                netCoverage = false;


         }//ends checking for network connection

    var watchID = null;


    function onDeviceReady() {


    checkConnection();







        // Get the most accurate position updates available on the
        // device.
        var options = { maximumAge:30000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess,
                                                   onError, options);

          // Update compass every 3 seconds
        var watchID = null;
}
        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
        //
        function onError(error) {
       alert('code: '+ error.code+'\n'+'message:'+ 
                                               error.message + '\n');
        }

$(document).ready(function() {

     /*****************************/
    (function worker() {
        try{                  

           if(netCoverage){             
                 $.ajax({url: 'http://www.myurl.com/add_position.php?&lat='
                 +lat+'&lon='+lon,
             success: function(data) {
            $("#geo_info").text(data);
            accIndex=0;//reset after submitting to server
              },
        error: function(request, error){
            $("#geo_info").text("Network error: "+error);
            $.ajax(this);
            return;
        },
        complete: function() {
        // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
        setTimeout(worker, 30000);
        }
        });
        }//ends checking for connection
        else{
          $("#geo_info").text('Unknown or no network connection.');
          setTimeout(worker, 30000);      //After calling this 
         //method few times      in              weak data coverage,
          // the app crashes with no warning
        }
        }catch(err){

        $("#geo_info").text('ALMOST CRASHED, '+err.message);

             $.ajax(this);
        return;
        }


        })();

    /*************************************************/
});

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geo_info">Watching geolocation...</p>
        <button onclick="clearWatch();">Clear Watch</button>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It make it much easier for you, and others, to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why not listen to [online](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online) & [offline](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline) event?

**online**

This event fires when an application goes online, and the device becomes connected to the Internet.

```
document.addEventListener("online", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

**offline**

The event fires when an application goes offline, and the device is not connected to the Internet.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Hope this is helpful to you!